# ISBX/apprtc-ios does not work on iOS 13 - no video not working

Tags: ios, apprtc, apprtcdemo

I am using apprtc-ios from https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios for our video calling project. It is working fine on iOS 12 & iOS 11.

After upgrading to my device to iOS 13, it seems the front camera does not record video and send it to the other party - If phone A & phone B are having a video calling session, the little video preview square on phone A (iOS 13) turns black. On phone B (iOS 12), there is no video sent by phone A - The whole screen is black, except for the little preview square. The audio conversation is working fine, though.

I checked camera permission - it is on for the app.

And I traced the code. cameraID for the front camera (on iOS 13 phone) is successfully obtained during the video call session.

After several hours of trial and error, I still got no clue. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: have you checked or followed this [link](https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios/issues/153) guidelines?

Comment: YES But not get Success

Answer (score 1):

HeIIO

I suggest you to use stasel instead (https://github.com/stasel/WebRTC-iOS)

I managed to send and receive thanks to this, by the way I had to use RTCEAGLVideoView instead of MTL and VP8 instead of H264 to be able to see the video from simulator (ios 13)

:)